# Creating hrefs to subdomains with localhost during development

Tags: angular, proxy, routes, localhost, href

I have several angular applications I would like to have links that go to each other.

For example in App1 I may have the following `<a href="app2.apps.com">App2</a>`. This works when the application is live, but during development, this does not work as app2 is being hosted on `localhost:50001`.

Is there a way to setup some type of proxy that captures my subdomains and routes them to the proper localhost during development?

Comment: You can make use of `environment.ts` file, [this](https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/) might help.

Comment: What operating system are you on? You can set this up with the hosts file on Windows. But it would probably be better to use the environment stuff in Angular.

Comment: @cyberpirate92 Thank you so simple yet effective.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel I am on Windows 10 Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli, you can make use of the **environment.ts** file under `/src/environments`.

You can define environment specific values in these environment files

```
environment.<some-environment-name>.ts
```

Example:

**environment.prod.ts** (Production environment)

```
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    api: {
        baseUrl: "http://app2.apps.com"
    },
    // some other properties if required
};
```

And another object for for development

**environment.ts** (dev environment)

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    api: {
        baseUrl: "http://localhost:50001"
    },
    // some other properties if required
};
```

If you have any more environments, you can additional environment files,

**environment.stage.ts** (staging environment)

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    api: {
        baseUrl: "http://app2.stagingapp.com"
    },
    // some other properties if required
};
```

Then, declare them in `angular-cli.json` under `apps` property

```
apps: {
    ..
    ..
    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",  // this should be imported in all the components/services etc
    "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "stage": "environments/environment.stage.ts"
    }
}
```

To use these values anywhere else (Components, Services etc)

```
import { environment } from ../environments/environment
```

and then use it

**foo.service.ts**

```
private readonly API_URL = `${environment.api.baseUrl}/foo`

public getFoo() {
    return this._http.get(API_URL);
}
```

**NOTE:** Never import a specific environment file in any of the components or services,

for example,

You should **NEVER** do this

```
import { environment } from ../environments/environment.prod; // NEVER do this
```

instead

When running with `ng serve`, use the `--environment` or `--env` option to specify the environment values and angular-cli will take care of the rest.

```
ng serve --env=prod  // uses values in environment.prod.ts
ng serve --env=stage // uses values in environment.stage.ts
ng serve             // uses values in environment.ts
```

When doing a `ng build`, use the `--prod` flag for production builds

```
ng build --prod
```

To build with other environments, you can use the `--env` option to specify the environment

```
ng build --env=stage
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so this works, but angular flags localhost hrefs as unsafe. Is there anyway around this?